# PHP Mail form not generating mail

Tags: php, forms, email

OK, my php email script is hosted on another server to my form. It has worked fine until recently, but a couple of unrelated changes seem to have buggered things up. I think I have an idea what might be going on, but let me explain the problem first.

At first I thought it was an issue with depricated !eregi commands. So, I changed them all to !preg_match, but that apparently wasn't the only issue.

The form appears to work, there are no errors being reported, and the success page is parsing, but no email is ever sent (yes, I checked my spam folder). Around the same time the issues started, I moved the website and domain that the original php mail script is hosted on to a different server that (one that I can't host php files on), but kept the php mail script on the old server. Of course, without the domain pointing to that web server the external referencing stopped working. So, I just dropped the file into a subdomain on the old server, and re-referenced the form accordingly. It now connects fine, and as I said, parses the script through to the success page.

The email hosting for this server was never changed. So, ththere shouldn't be an issue, but I think the problem is related to that domain name change. Any thoughts? Script and form address below:

```
    <?php

ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
//  set the EMAIL TO options
    $email_to = "jr@creativeheat.co.uk";
    $email_bcc = "jr@creativeheat.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "Website booking inquiry";
//  grab referal info from POST
    $path = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $referer = $path[2];
//  redirect to error page
    function died($error) {
    $path = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $referer = $path[2];
        header( 'Location: http://'.$referer.'/'.$error ) ;
        exit;
    }

//  grab the checkbox values and change them to strings
    if (isset($_POST['booking_0'])) { $book1 = $_POST['booking_0']; if( $book1 == 'Bedroom(s)') {   $book1 = "                  The Bedroom(s) \n"; }} else {$book1 = "\n";}
    if (isset($_POST['booking_1'])) { $book2 = $_POST['booking_1']; if( $book2 == 'Meeting Room') { $book2 = "                  The Meeting Room \n";}} else {$book2 = "\n";}
    if (isset($_POST['booking_2'])) { $book3 = $_POST['booking_2']; if( $book3 == 'Barn') { $book3 = "                  The Barn \n";   }} else {$book3 = "\n";}
    if (isset($_POST['booking_3'])) { $book4 = $_POST['booking_3']; if( $book4 == 'Campsite') { $book4 = "                  The Campsite \n";}} else {$book4 = "\n";}
//  clear the ERRORTYPE & ERROR_MESSAGE variables
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
//  then check for an all false in the checkbox group
    if (!isset($_POST['booking_0']) && !isset($_POST['booking_1']) && !isset($_POST['booking_2']) && !isset($_POST['booking_3'])) {
//  provided none of the checkboxes are ticked set the DIED function parameter to ERRORTYPE = BOOKINGERR
        $error_message = 'error';
        $errortype = 'bookingerr';
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
//  alternate bruteforce redirect to NO BOOKING TYPE SELECTED page
//      header( 'Location: http://'.$referer.'/booking/'.$errortype ) ;
    }

//  check everything else
//  reset the ERROR variables
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
//  check the ISSET state of the remaining required fields
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['number']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['adults']) ||
        !isset($_POST['children']) ||
        !isset($_POST['from_date']) ||
        !isset($_POST['to_date']) ||
        !isset($_POST['disabled']) ||
        !isset($_POST['parking']) ||
        !isset($_POST['general'])) {
//   redirect to GENERAL INVALIDATION page
        $error_message = 'error';
        $errortype = 'requirederror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }

//  set FIELD variables
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['number']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $adults = $_POST['adults']; // required
    $children = $_POST['children']; // required
    $fdate = $_POST['from_date']; // required
    $tdate = $_POST['to_date']; // required
    $disabled = $_POST['disabled']; // not required
    $parking = $_POST['parking']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['general']; // not required


//  begin INVALID field character checks
    $email_exp = "/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i";
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
//  redirect to INVALID EMAIL page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'emailinvalid';
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[a-z .'-]+$/i";
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
//  redirect to INVALID FIRSTNAME page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'fnameerror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
//  redirect to INVALID LASTNAME page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'lnameerror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(strlen($comments) < 2 && strlen($comments) > 0) {
//  redirect to INVALID COMMENTS page
        $error_message = 'error';
        $errortype = 'commentserror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[0-9 .-]+$/i";
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone)) {
//  redirect to INVALID TELEPHONE page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'telephoneerror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
//  failsafe
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($errortype) ;
    }


//  begin EMAIL MESSAGE creation
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
//  remove ILLEGAL data from submitted fields   
    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
//  set EMAIL_MESSAGE variable from data gathered from form 
    $email_message .= "Name:             ".clean_string($first_name)." ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact number:   ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email address:    ".clean_string($email_from)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Interested in availability of the following: \n";
    $email_message .= $book1.$book2.$book3.$book4."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date from:        ".clean_string($fdate)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date to:          ".clean_string($tdate)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Number of...\n";
    $email_message .= "Adults:           ".clean_string($adults)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Children:         ".clean_string($children)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Disabled?         ".clean_string($disabled)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Parking?          ".clean_string($parking)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Additional Information: \n\n";
    $email_message .= clean_string($comments);
//  create EMAIL HEADERS
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Bcc: '.$email_bcc."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
//  redirect to SUCCESS page
    header( 'Location: http://'.$referer.'/success' ) ;
    exit;
}
?>
```

form address: http://www.claverhammeetinghouse.org.uk/booking/

EDIT:

After installing PHPmailer the code now looks like this:

```
<?php
// new
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//end new

ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
//  set the EMAIL TO options
    $email_to = "jr@creativeheat.co.uk";
    $email_bcc = "jr@creativeheat.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "Website booking inquiry";
//  grab referal info from POST
    $path = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $referer = $path[2];
//  redirect to error page
    function died($error) {
    $path = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $referer = $path[2];
        header( 'Location: http://'.$referer.'/'.$error ) ;
        exit;
    }

//  grab the checkbox values and change them to strings
    if (isset($_POST['booking_0'])) { $book1 = $_POST['booking_0']; if( $book1 == 'Bedroom(s)') {   $book1 = "                  The Bedroom(s) \n"; }} else {$book1 = "\n";}
    if (isset($_POST['booking_1'])) { $book2 = $_POST['booking_1']; if( $book2 == 'Meeting Room') { $book2 = "                  The Meeting Room \n";}} else {$book2 = "\n";}
    if (isset($_POST['booking_2'])) { $book3 = $_POST['booking_2']; if( $book3 == 'Barn') { $book3 = "                  The Barn \n";   }} else {$book3 = "\n";}
    if (isset($_POST['booking_3'])) { $book4 = $_POST['booking_3']; if( $book4 == 'Campsite') { $book4 = "                  The Campsite \n";}} else {$book4 = "\n";}
//  clear the ERRORTYPE & ERROR_MESSAGE variables
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
//  then check for an all false in the checkbox group
    if (!isset($_POST['booking_0']) && !isset($_POST['booking_1']) && !isset($_POST['booking_2']) && !isset($_POST['booking_3'])) {
//  provided none of the checkboxes are ticked set the DIED function parameter to ERRORTYPE = BOOKINGERR
        $error_message = 'error';
        $errortype = 'bookingerr';
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
//  alternate bruteforce redirect to NO BOOKING TYPE SELECTED page
//      header( 'Location: http://'.$referer.'/booking/'.$errortype ) ;
    }

//  check everything else
//  reset the ERROR variables
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
//  check the ISSET state of the remaining required fields
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['number']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['adults']) ||
        !isset($_POST['children']) ||
        !isset($_POST['from_date']) ||
        !isset($_POST['to_date']) ||
        !isset($_POST['disabled']) ||
        !isset($_POST['parking']) ||
        !isset($_POST['general'])) {
//   redirect to GENERAL INVALIDATION page
        $error_message = 'error';
        $errortype = 'requirederror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }

//  set FIELD variables
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['number']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $adults = $_POST['adults']; // required
    $children = $_POST['children']; // required
    $fdate = $_POST['from_date']; // required
    $tdate = $_POST['to_date']; // required
    $disabled = $_POST['disabled']; // not required
    $parking = $_POST['parking']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['general']; // not required


//  begin INVALID field character checks
    $email_exp = "/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i";
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
//  redirect to INVALID EMAIL page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'emailinvalid';
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[a-z .'-]+$/i";
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
//  redirect to INVALID FIRSTNAME page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'fnameerror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
//  redirect to INVALID LASTNAME page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'lnameerror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(strlen($comments) < 2 && strlen($comments) > 0) {
//  redirect to INVALID COMMENTS page
        $error_message = 'error';
        $errortype = 'commentserror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[0-9 .-]+$/i";
    $errortype = "";
    $error_message = "";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone)) {
//  redirect to INVALID TELEPHONE page
    $error_message = 'error';
    $errortype = 'telephoneerror' ;
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($errortype) ;
        }
    }
//  failsafe
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($errortype) ;
    }


//  begin EMAIL MESSAGE creation
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
//  remove ILLEGAL data from submitted fields   
    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
//  set EMAIL_MESSAGE variable from data gathered from form 
    $email_message .= "Name:             ".clean_string($first_name)." ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact number:   ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email address:    ".clean_string($email_from)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Interested in availability of the following: \n";
    $email_message .= $book1.$book2.$book3.$book4."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date from:        ".clean_string($fdate)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date to:          ".clean_string($tdate)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Number of...\n";
    $email_message .= "Adults:           ".clean_string($adults)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Children:         ".clean_string($children)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Disabled?         ".clean_string($disabled)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Parking?          ".clean_string($parking)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Additional Information: \n\n";
    $email_message .= clean_string($comments);
//  create EMAIL HEADERS
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Bcc: '.$email_bcc."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
//new
    new PHPMailer($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
//end new

// old  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
//end old
//  redirect to SUCCESS page
    header( 'Location: http://'.$referer.'/success' ) ;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Try PHPMailer API which has lot of options and easy to send email in 1 line.. https://github.com/logindian/PHPMailer

Comment: Remove the @ from in front of mail for a start

Comment: Have tried it with @ removed to capture error codes, there are none.

Comment: Will give php mailer a try as well, thanks.

Comment: ok, I added PHPmailer to the subdomain's root directory and have changed my code accordingly, still no joy:

Comment: If you're getting no PHP errors, have you tried checking the servers mail logs to see if it's being blocked? Maybe you need to use SMTP authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Try using only "\n" instead of "\r\n" on $headers as documented in the PHP reference. http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php